# How to compare two large dictionaries?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I want to compare 2 dictionaries

1. dEmpty - key(type:range), value(type:range)
2. dFilled -key(type:value), value(type:range)

I have code like this

```
For Each eRD In dEmpty.Keys
    Set eRD = dEmpty.Item(eRDesc)
    For Each e In dFilled.Keys
        Dim inStrIndexFound as long, inStrIndexFoundDeep As Long

        letterNum = InStr(e, dFilled.Item(e)),
        If letterNum > 0 Then
            newStrToFind = Mid(e, letterNum, Len(dFilled.Item(e)) + lettersCount)
        End If

        inStrIndexFoundDeep = InStr(eRD.Value, newStrToFind)
        inStrIndexFound = InStr(eRD.Value, dFilled.Item(e ))

        If inStrIndexFound > 0 Then

            If inStrIndexFoundDeep > 0 Then
                eRD.Value = dFilled.Item(e)
                Cells(eRD.Row, 1) = "No" 
            End If
            With eRD.Characters(start:=inStrIndexFound, Length:=Len(dFilled.Item(e))).Font
                SomeAction
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

How can I improve and optimize this macro, it's takes a very long time on big dictionaries (for example, 30k elements in dEmpty and 10k dFilled).

What actions in my code are the most expensive for macro speed?

Comment: You are looping for each item of  `dEmpty` though all items of `dFilled`  that's 30k*10k = 300m iterations. I don't understand all your tinkering with `inStrIndexFound`, but it is surely not the idea of a dictionary to manually search items.

Comment: I know  about 30k*10k :( I tried to find text from dFilled in dEmpty.value. For example, dEmpty.value = "hi", dFilled = "Blah blah blah, hi, blah blah blah", and i want to make some action with the row (eRD.row), where i have found this "hi"

Comment: Are the substrings that you are trying to find arbitrary or are they delimited in some fashion (e.g. space-delimited)? Perhaps you could create a new dictionary out of `dEmpty` where the keys are candidate substrings obtained by splitting the strings on the delimiter. Your current code isn't using `dEmpty` as a dictionary. With the overhead, you are using it as an inferior array. Also, the point when VBA code starts doing linear searches over tens of thousands of items is the point when using an actual database should at least be considered. Slow VBA is often a database waiting to be born.

Comment: It will be faster if i use 1 dictionary and for each element in this dictionary will use Find (in column with 40k rows), than FindNext, until FindNext is nothing and the same to each element? I read, that find and findnext are very slow or it's not truth?

Comment: It is hard to say anything without knowing what the data looks like and exactly what you are trying to do. Please give a [mcve] which someone can copy-paste and directly run.

Comment: I will check my variant, if it will be slow too, i will reask. Thanks all for answers